# arcpy TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sum, arcpy

Trying to do some seemingly simple field calculations via UpdateCursor in ArcGIS 10.1 and getting an error about not being able to iterate floats. Here's my code--some stuff is commented out b/c it's not important to my question so just ignore it.

```
    #import arcpy module
    import arcpy

    #doing some fancy math
    import math

#message to let you know the script started
print "Begin Field Calculation for age-adjusted-rate."

#input shapefile
inputFC = 'C:\\blahblah.shp'

#variable to define the new field name
Field_Name = ['Age_Adj_R', 'wt_1', 'wt_2', 'wt_3']

#add the new Fields
#arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, Field_Name[0], "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "",        "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
#arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, Field_Name[1], "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
#arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, Field_Name[2], "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
#arcpy.AddField_management(inputFC, Field_Name[3], "DOUBLE", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

#list variable for the fields in the table that will be used
fields = ["Cnt1", "Cnt2", "Cnt3", "Pop1", "Pop2", "Pop3", "Crude_Rate", "Age_Adj_R", "wt_1", "wt_2", "wt_3"]
#wt_age_avg = [0.2869, 0.5479, 0.1652]

#populate the weighted average fields
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(inputFC, ["wt_1", "wt_2", "wt_3"])
for x in xrange(0, 51):
    cursor.insertRow([0.2869, 0.5479, 0.1652])
del cursor

#function to perform the field calculation using an update cursor
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputFC, fields) as cursor:
for row in cursor: #iterate through each row
    if not -99 in row: #check for missing values
        row[7] = str(sum((row[6]) * ((row[0] * row[8]) + (row[1] * row[9]) + (row[2] * row[10]))) #do the calculation
    else:
        row[7] = 0 #missing values found, place a null response
    cursor.updateRow(row) #save the calculations
del row  #release the variables

#acknowledge completion
   print "Calculation Completed."
```

error in IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blahblah.py", line 48, in <module>
    row[7] = str(sum((row[6]) * ((row[0] * row[8]) + (row[1] * row[9]) + (row[2] * row[10])))) #do the calculation
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Ok--but I thought I changed it to a string before it would even populate the fields....I have no idea how to get this calculation to work. It should look something like:

sum(crude_rate* sum(weighted_averages))

If my way of using constant value fields doesn't work, I have also tried passing the values as variables (see variable: wt_age_avg) without luck. Also using other summation functions like math.fsum didnt' work either.

Comment: `print(row)` does it print out a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sum()` expects an iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>   Sums start and the items of an **iterable** from
>   left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The
>   iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not
>   allowed to be a string.

BUT here's the fun part: You don't need to use `sum()` here! You can just do instead:

```
row[7] = str( (row[6] * row[0] * row[8]) + 
              (row[1] * row[9]) + 
              (row[2] * row[10]) )
```

Comment: hmm Bernie, that's not quite what I'm looking for but you've given me an idea of how to fix it...

Comment: @geneari: We really like people who get ideas of how to fix stuff here. Welcome to SO, and hopefully we'll see more of you around. Take care.

Comment: Sorry I was snippy just several hours of being dumb will do that. You let me see it a different (and consequently correct) way. Thanks.

Comment: No problem at all. I deleted my earlier comment since it no longer applies to anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is sufficient, you don't need the `sum()` call. The error is calling `sum(number)`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct but should you wish to use `sum()` for readability purposes, you can pass your values as a list...

```
row[7] = str(sum([row[6] * row[0] * row[8],
                  row[1] * row[9],
                  row[2] * row[10]] ))
```

Comment: Basic, that is a great suggestion for future reference, thanks!